# How to rename btrfs subvolumes on Fedora 38?

Tags: linux, backup, fedora, grub

I tried to install `timeshift`, but it cannot find my subvolumes, because they are not named with '@':

```bash
sudo btrfs sub list /
ID 256 gen 18303 top level 5 path root
ID 257 gen 18303 top level 5 path home
```

```bash
sudo btrfs filesystem show
Label: 'fedora_localhost-live'  uuid: b4af3fb7-bd48-4d59-96c0-0a71385a8fb8
        Total devices 1 FS bytes used 60.93GiB
        devid    1 size 236.89GiB used 67.02GiB path /dev/nvme0n1p3
```

I guess I need to rename them, some users advise to use `mv` (but how?) and update GRUB, but I'm a newbie at `btrfs` and I don't know what commands I should run and what files I should edit without breaking my entire system

My /etc/fstab/

```
UUID=b4af3fb7-bd48-4d59-96c0-0a71385a8fb8 /                       btrfs   subvol=root,compress=zstd:1 0 0
UUID=52ff126f-6a73-41df-9312-15d2ae1fbf91 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=3D19-2F96          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
UUID=b4af3fb7-bd48-4d59-96c0-0a71385a8fb8 /home                   btrfs   subvol=home,compress=zstd:1 0 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my partitions thanks to the answer of @piorunz on Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.user/c/4Qg3Fxv_pHo

```
1. Find out what is the path to your root partition. You can use:
$ lsblk | grep "part /"
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1 0 512M 0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2 0 37.3G 0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3 0 172G 0 part /mnt/ssd

So in my case / is on nvme0n1p2. Therefore, full path is /dev/nvme0n1p2.
Note that.

2. Boot to Linux USB stick. I used Linux Mint.

3. mount your / partition and navigate to it in terminal

4. Change btrfs subvolume name using sudo mv, in my example:
sudo mv @rootfs @

5. Edit /etc/fstab on your root partition, to tell it new name of
subvolume, like so: subvol=@, full line example here:
UUID=77ba5989-5d64-4929-9145-ede6751a4102 /
btrfs
noatime,nodiratime,space_cache=v2,ssd,compress-force=zstd:6,subvol=@ 0 1

6. sync && sudo reboot, remove USB stick

7. You will be greeted by grub emergency console of your system, as grub
don't know yet where is root partition now. Boot to your Linux using
following commands in grub console:

ls - use that to find where your root partition is in grub nomenclature.
You can do things like ls, then ls (hd5,gpt2)/@/ to browse contents to
btrfs partition to eventually find your root. Note that my root is on
(hd5,gpt2), which is similar to /dev/nvme0n1p2 (partition2 = gpt2).

Once you have your grub partition number, do:

set root=(hd5,gpt2)
linux /@/boot/vmlinuz/5.10.0-9-amd64 root=dev/nvme0n1p2 rootflags=subvol=@
initrd /@/boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-9-amd64
boot

As you see, set root=(hd5,gpt2) uses grub nomenclature and
root=dev/nvme0n1p2 uses normal nomenclature from lsblk.

8. So you are logged in to your system as normal. Generate new grub
config and install it into place:
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

9. Reboot, grub will load as normal and you are fully in @ btrfs
subvolume and can use Timeshift now. Profit!
```

If you struggle on step 7, check your default grub options and change root to `@`.

If you have problems on step 8, run:

```bash
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2-efi.cfg
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg
```